# Proguard Obfuscation Options. How to remove android.suppport.v4?

Tags: java, android, obfuscation, proguard

How to prevent to create in dex (jar) files android.suppport.v4 folder while obfuscation using Proguard? I'm always see something folder tree like in screenshot!

[image]

Comment: If you don't want the library, why do you have it in your project?

Comment: I wanna small size of apk-file. I'm using just command line to compile APK file.

Comment: That does not answer my question. If you don't want the library, why do you have it in your project?

Comment: In my project I just have a simple MainActivity.java file . If I compile by command line I just have this file in resultant APK file. It works properly on my Phone. But when I use obfuscation the size of file dramatically increase because of this new code which is created by proguard.

Comment: ProGuard is not creating any code. Those classes are coming from `android-support-v4.jar`, which is part of your project (e.g., `libs/` directory, `compile` statement in `build.gradle`). Sometimes that library is added when you do not need it as part of creating a new project, so I suggest that you [read about the Android Support libraries](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html), determine whether or not you need that JAR, and remove it if you do not.

Comment: Does it mean if I use android:minSdkVersion="9" I can delete android-support-v4.jar ?

Comment: Your `minSdkVersion` does not indicate whether or not you need `android-support-v4.jar`. Whether you are using *classes* from `android-support-v4.jar` determines if you need `android-support-v4.jar`. Most of these classes will have `support.v4.` as part of their package name, as seen in things like `import` statements.

Comment: Thanks for explaination.